# Refer to an enum inside a struct

Tags: c++, enums

I have an struct defined like this in a header file:

```
struct MessageA {
   enum Status {
      eReady, eNotReady 
   };
};
```

Later, when I try to use this enum:

```
#include <MessageA.hh>
...
if( status != MessageA.Status.eReady ) continue;
```

I get the error:

```
expected primary-expression before '.' token
'Status' has not been declared
```

I tried the following and it worked:

```
if( status != MessageA::eReady ) continue;
```

However, if use:

```
if( status != MessageA::Status::eReady ) continue;
```

Then I get the error:

```
   Status is not a class or a namespace
```

If I needed to specify the name of the enum fully qualified (such as if there were multiple enums with the same values inside) how should I do it?

Comment: `if( status != MessageA::eReady ) continue;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the scope operator:

```
MessageA::Status::eReady;
```

Also note that prior to C++11 labels of enums were not scoped in which case you would be using the following code:

```
MessageA::eReady;
```

Comment: MessageA::eReady works. However, MessageA::Status::eReady gives the error "MessageA::Status is not a class or a namespace"

Comment: @TylerDurden In which case you are using the pre-C++11 compiler. See the second part of my answer.

Comment: does that mean that in pre11 you cannot have different enums with the same values inside of them because it would be ambiguous?

Comment: @TylerDurden Use `enum classes` or wrap your enums into namespaces.

Comment: @TylerDurden You can hack together a scoped enum in pre11 with `struct Foo { enum { bar, baz }; };`, though it won't have all the same benefits as the strongly-typed enum of C++11. Note that enum access/scoping method [B works for 03, while all three do for 11](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53bef88c637ecff9)

Answer (score 1):

Put `;` in end of the `struct` :

```
struct MessageA {
   enum Status {
      eReady, eNotReady 
   };
};
```

Then use of `enum` elements like bellow :

```
int main()
{
    if (MessageA::Status::eNotReady == 0)
        printf("ok");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That is a typo in the question. The header file compiles fine.